# transparent outside and opaque inside

Tags: dae

I have an element in my model, which is, when exported e.g. to DAE or obj, turns "inside out"[image]

However, within blender itself this element is rendered absolutely ok, both Eevee and Cycles:
[image]
[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be a problem of flipped normals, some softwares only display the normal side of the face. select your object and in *Edit* mode press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you so much! It has worked perfectly. Is there a similarly easy way to make all faces "double-sided"?

Comment: I'm not sure there's any way, I guess you need to make sure your normals are flipped the right way in Blender